# I wish std::shared_ptr can be written like MyClass＠ ptr = @(new MyClass());

Tags: c++11, smart-pointers

After a lot of `std::shared_ptr<myNs::MyClass>` are written, 
I wish pointers can be written like:

```
MyClass* rawPtr = new MyClass(); // raw pointer
MyClass@ refPtr = @(new MyClass()); // std::shared_ptr
MyClass# gcPtr = #(new MyClass()); // GC pointer, for future
```

so the function:

```
void CRAIIMFCApplication1View::ConsumeThreadResult(
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ThreadParam> > threadParamsVecPtr,
    std::shared_ptr<CalculationResult> calculationResultPtr)
{
   ...
}
```

can be written shortly like:

```
void CRAIIMFCApplication1View::ConsumeThreadResult(
        std::vector<ThreadParam@> threadParamsVecPtr,
        CalculationResult@ calculationResultPtr)
{
   ...
}
```

Is there a trick to do that?

**====================== Update1 =========================**

Many thanks to @tahsmith.
Now I use the followings `typedef`

```
template<typename T> using $ = std::shared_ptr<T>;
template<typename T> using vector$ = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T> >;
```

The code can be written like:

```
void CRAIIMFCApplication1View::ConsumeThreadResult(
        vector$<ThreadParam> threadParamPtrVec,
        $<CalculationResult> calculationResultPtr)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: where are you getting this syntax from??

Comment: How about `typedef` ? `typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ThreadParam> > ThreadParamPtrs`;

Comment: or `template<typename T> using SharePtrVector = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>`

Answer (score 0):

`std::shared_ptr` is a (standard) library component and you propose `@` to be a C++ feature. Using a feature for a library component is quite an underutilized design of a programming language!

Conveniently one may always use `typedef` or `using` for aliasing a user defined type. e.g.

`template<typename T> using Ptr = std::shared_ptr<T>;`

`template<typename T> using Ptrs = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T> >; // or PtrVec`

Using non-alphanumeric symbols like `$` is not a good idea.

Comment: I wish C++ will have more syntax sugar to make the code more readable. For example, in C#, `string` is not a primitive type but can be used in `switch`.

Comment: @Zach, from one of the Bjarne Stroustrup's interview, I remember him saying that, 'In C++ if something can be achieved using a library, then they avoid adding a feature for it.' Possibly to avoid adding complexities to the already complex grammar of the language. However in C++14/17, I see few additions in this regard where instead of keywords, they have added tokens, which will have meaning when used in certain context. e.g. C++11 `final` and `override` are not keywords, but if used in certain context they generate certain meaning.